# How can i correctly pass arguments to classbasedviews testing Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

I want to test some views in DRF project.

The problem comes when I try to check views that have arguments in the urls.

urls.py

```
    url(r'^(?Pcompany_hash>[\d\w]+)/(?Ptimestamp>[\.\d]*)/employees/$',
        EmployeeList.as_view(), name='employeelist'),
```

[edit: "<" in url has been deleted in purpose, just it isnt considered a tag and thus not shown]

views.py

```
    class EmployeeList(ListCreateAPIView):
        serializer_class = EmployeeDirectorySerializer

        def inner_company(self):
            company_hash = self.kwargs['company_hash']
            return get_company(company_hash)

        def get_queryset(self):
            return Employee.objects.filter(company=self.inner_company())
```

test.py

```
class ApiTests(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
        self.staff = mommy.make('directory.Employee', user__is_staff=True)
        self.employee = mommy.make('directory.Employee')

        self.hash = self.employee.company.company_hash

    def getResponse(self, url, myView, kwargs):
        view = myView.as_view()
        request = self.factory.get(url, kwargs)

        force_authenticate(request, user=user)

        response = view(request)
        return response

    def test_EmployeeList(self):
        kwargs = {'timestamp': 0, 'company_hash': self.hash}
        url = reverse('employeelist', kwargs=kwargs)
        testedView = EmployeeList

        response = self.getResponse(url, testedView,
                kwargs=kwargs)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I'm getting this error

```
    company_hash = self.kwargs['company_hash']
KeyError: 'company_hash'
```

That is the args aren't been passed to the view.

I've tried in so many different ways to pass by the args, can't find a solution.

Any help is welcomed!

Comment: your `urls.py` entry is wrong. Try with `url(r'^(?P<company_hash>[\d\w]+)/(?P<timestamp>[\.\d]*)/employees/$',
        EmployeeList.as_view(), name='employeelist'),`

Comment: Thanks Pynchia but it isnt wrong just had to quit the < because else was consider a tag and thus deleted. Could have scaped it tho

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just found the problem!!

I was using APIRequestFactory()
and should have been using the build in client factory from the APITestCase test class from Django Rest Framework

Comment: I did not find any built-in client factory for `APITestCase`. Downvoting because you don't provide any code example (imports), nor documentation link. Everywhere in the examples it is common to use `APIRequestFactory` with `APITestCase` and I spent some time to check your solution, so to me it is misleading.

Answer (score 5):

Check your regex syntax in your URL conf. You aren't capturing the named group correctly. You have

```
(?<P
```

rather than

```
(?P<
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

-James

Comment: Why the down vote? Both of the answers are correct, and my example is the answer I also sent to the Django-users group, which contains the typo I've pointed out here. Also I had some terrible formatting problems due to the same issue as the OP.

Comment: Hello James, thanks for pointing out the problem in the urls ... its correct that should be formated properlly and in fact in the project is done correctly  ... just i took out the "<" because else stackoverflow considers it a html tag and thus deletes it.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to specify your kwargs again when calling `get()` method:

```
...
...
    def getResponse(self, url, myView, kwargs):
        view = myView.as_view()
        request = self.factory.get(url, kwargs)
        ...
        response = view(request, company_hash=kwargs['company_hash'])
        return response
```

So your argument will be passed correctly.

**NB:** i used this solution based on my experience with the mother class of **APIRequestfactory**, Django **RequestFactory**.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `kwargs` twice: into `reverse(...)` and into `view(...)`:

```
def test_EmployeeList(self):
    # some init here
    auth_user = ...
    hash = ...
    # form kwargs for url /<company_hash>/<timestamp>/employees/
    kwargs = {'company_hash': hash, 'timestamp': 0}
    # form url itself
    url = reverse('employeelist', kwargs=kwargs)
    # then form factory and request
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    request = factory.get(url)
    force_authenticate(request, user=auth_user)
    # get view
    view = EmployeeList.as_view()
    # run view
    # here you pass kwargs again!
    response = view(request, **kwargs)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

PS. Actually @bachir-mehemmel's answer lead me to that code but he is wrong telling `kwargs` should be passed to `get` (I think he means `factory.get`). If you open `factory.get` implementation you'll see that it is used for payload and not for url.